# Proof that the Sturm-Liouville operator is positive

Tags: operator-theory

Define the Sturm-Liouville operator $L$ on $[a,b]$ such that $Lu = \frac{1}{\omega}[-(pu')'+qu]$, $p$ and $\omega$ being strictly positive real valued function, and $q$ a positive real valued function.

The inner product is defined as such : $\int_a^b u(x)\overline{v(x)}\omega(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $

The question asks to prove that the operator is positive, i.e. $(Lu,u)\ge0$ (I believe they really mean positive semi-definite).

I got so far:

$(Lu,u)= \int_a^b q|u|^2 \mathrm{d}x + \int_a^b p|u'|^2 \mathrm{d}x - [pu'\bar{u}]^b_a $

Now I don't really understand how the boundary conditions come into play... any one knows?

Comment: I can't answer your question fully and don't know about your knowledge but would looking at orthogonal polynomials help? They are normally solution of a very similar kind of ODE to that of the Sturm-Liouville oprator.

Sorry if this is something you already know but since you don't mention perhaps it could be worth a look.

Comment: [Here is a different question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695709) with a closely related problem.