# Prove that $L[X] = \frac{(pX')' - qX}{r}$ is a formally self-adjoint operator for continuous $p, q,r$ functions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$\Large\textbf{Given Problem}$$

Let $p,q,r$ be continuous functions on $[0,L]$ such that $p'$ is also continuous, and $p$ and $r$ are positive.  Define
$$L[X] = \dfrac{(pX')' - qX}{r}$$
Show, using integration by parts, that $L$ is a formally self-adjoint operator.

$$\large{\textbf{My Attempt and Thoughts for this Problem}}$$

I need to show that

$$\langle Lu,v\rangle_r = \langle u,Lv\rangle_r + \text{some boundary terms}$$

where $r$ is the weight function.  First, I evaluate $\langle Lu,v\rangle_r$, which gives

$$\begin{aligned}
\langle Lu,v \rangle_r &= \int_0^L \dfrac{(pu')' - qu}{r}\cdot vr\,dx\\
&= \int_0^L (v(pu')' - vqu)\,dx\\
&= \int_0^L v(pu')'\,dx - \int_0^L vqu\,dx\\
&= vpu'\bigg\vert_{x = 0}^{x = L} - \int_0^L u'v'p\,dx - \int_0^L quv\,dx
\end{aligned}$$

where $vpu'\bigg\vert_{x = 0}^{x = L}$ is some constant. Then, for the right-hand side

$$\begin{aligned}
\langle u,Lv\rangle_r &= \int_0^L ((pv')' - qv)u\,dx\\
&= \int_0^L u(pv')'\,dx - \int_0^L quv\,dx\\
&= upv'\bigg\vert_{x = 0}^{x = L} - \int_0^L u'v'p\,dx - \int_0^L quv\,dx
\end{aligned}$$

where $upv'\bigg\vert_{x = 0}^{x = L}$ is some constant.  Noticing both equations have same integrals, but different constants, can I conclude that the equality holds, or am I on the wrong path, or will I need to reconsider my method?